# why xml:space="preserve" is not honored by php xslt transformation

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I try to produce some DOCX documents by transforming document.xml in the DOCX and reinjecting it back.

All works fine except for this piece of code:

```
<w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
</w:r>
```

which after transformation becomes:

```
<w:r>
<w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
</w:r>
```

If I put some text, other than a single space, in the w:t it works ok.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

P.S. I do the transformation with php 5.5.9 shipped with XAMPP 1.8.3 XsltProcessor.
And another note: The same code worked fine with an older version of XAMPP (1.8.1 if I remember correctly)

Followed nwellnhof solution and replaced the piece of code as follows:

```
<w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></w:t>
</w:r>
```

and it worked.

@nwellnhof thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to some changes introduced in *libxml2* version 2.9.0 which *libxslt* didn't account for. [This commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxslt/commit/?id=7cb08dacadf7e1cf88ee2f45815251b61bffcde6) fixes the issue and will be part of the next *libxslt* release.

Comment: Thank you nwellnhof for your answer. At least I know is not my code to blame. Do you know some workaround on the problem until the next libxslt release?

Comment: @rocordial For source documents, you can use [`xsl:strip-space` and `xsl:preserve-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#strip). For stylesheets, you can use [`xsl:text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Creating-Text).